# Program won't Print a string array C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on this program for awhile, but it refuses to cooperate on this last little stretch. The point of the program is to sift a data file into three arrays, sort the arrays, then print them out into a table. The problem I'm having appears to be with the table. The program is divided into four functions, and when I attempt to debug, it won't show the productName array in the function.

The malfunctioning segment of code looks like this:

```
void printReport (string productName[], int numberinStock[], float price[], int number_of_products)
{
    float totalPrice; 

    cout << setw(18) << " " << "Friendly Grocer Store Inventory" << setw(17) << " " << endl; 
    cout << setw(18) << "Inventory Item" << setw(16) << "Number in Stock" << setw(16) << "Unit Price" << setw(16) << "Total Sales" << endl; 
    for (int count=0; count <number_of_products-1; count++)
    {
        cout << setw(18) << productName[count] << setw(16) << numberinStock[count] << setw(16) << std::setprecision(2) << price[count] << setw(16) << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << price[count]*numberinStock[count] << endl; 
    }
    cout << "Total Price:  " << totalPrice; 
}
```

It will print everything else, but not the `productName`.
Some debugging statements outside of the for loop like `cout << productName[1]` will print out the proper `productName` but it's completely blank on the actual report. 
After some debugging it seems like after printing the `productName` in the for loop every item after that overwrites the product name.

For example just leaving `cout << setw(18) << productName[count] << setw(16) << numberinStock[count] << endl;`

will produce

> "               3s"
>   "              10h"
>   "               2a"

The product names there are Mangoes, Sandwich, and pizza.

I'm at a loss. Where did I mess up?

Comment: Wild guess: all your `productName`s end with a `'\r'`?

Comment: no. they're all stored in a .dat file and are just like common household names. (like right now it's mangoes, sandwich and pizza). Also, I found that putting an endl; right after productName and then having the rest of the information on a second line is helping majorly. The moment I introduce setw, it sort of overwrites productName.

Comment: That the `endl` helps suggests that you actually do have `'\r'`s in your strings. What platform a) are you running on, and b) was the file created on? [If the file was created on Windows and you're running on something *nixish, that would be natural when `dos2unix` was forgotten; If you're running on Windows, did you open the file as text or binary?]

Comment: the file was originally created using DevC++, and has been worked on in puTTY for the last week or so. It ran fine on DevC++, but basically crashed the moment it moved to puTTY. I think I've only run the file in text, but I'm not honestly sure what that means. I'm opening it in puTTY, editing with pico, and compiling with g++, and ./a.out is the command I'm using to run the program.

Comment: Can you split that into parts where you do `cout << setw(18); cout << prductName[count];` etc?

Comment: You know that Windows uses `\r\n` as line ending instead of just `\n` like almost everybody else? When you open a file in text mode, the OS converts the line endings so the programme sees only `\n`. When you open it in binary mode, the OS doesn't, and if your programme strips only the `\n`, you're left with strings with trailing `\r`s.

Comment: That caused a random output of numbers in the first column. Don't know why that's happening. And when I put productName on a separate line with an endl; it works fine.

Comment: how am I supposed to fix an invisible thing? (that had more sass than I intended, I'm just honestly confused)

Comment: Check the definition of setw(), the part about `Data races`.

Comment: the files are opened and then closed, but in different functions that don't occur concurrently

Answer (score 0):

You might have screwed up passing the data into the function.  If you set up test arrays in the function it should be printing correctly.

To [pass arrays in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) use the arrayname.
eg

```
int main ()
{
  string productName[] = {"mango"}; 
  ...
  printReport(productName, numofProduct);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The arrays appear to be being passed correctly, and they're being passed the same way they do in the other four functions in the program (which appear to be running fine).

Comment: @user2345261 Was making a guess.  Garbage output is often caused by reading the wrong memory eg `productName[number_of_products]` or forgetting to initilize the memory eg `int num =0;`.